# mysql add key does not work

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT adressid, adressname FROM kino_adressen WHERE city ='Seattle'
```

I wanted to create an index like this

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD KEY index_abc(adressid, adressname(40))
```

But when I then check it by using:

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT adressid, adressname FROM kino_adressen WHERE city ='Seattle'
```

It says

```
type = ALL
possible keys = NULL
key = NULL 
...rows = 106
```

Can anyone give some piece of advice how to do this properly ?

// edit:
Another problem I do not understand:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
titel,
regie,
darsteller,
filmbild,
kino_filme.filmid,
kino_filme.beschreibung,
fsk,
filmlaenge,
verleih,
sprachfassung
FROM
    kino_filme
LEFT JOIN kino_terminefilme ON (
    kino_terminefilme.filmid = kino_filme.filmid
)
LEFT JOIN kino_termine ON (
    kino_terminefilme.terminid = kino_termine.terminid
)
LEFT JOIN kino_kinos ON (
    kino_kinos.kinoid = kino_termine.kinoid
)
LEFT JOIN kino_adressen ON (
    kino_adressen.adressid = kino_kinos.adressid
)
WHERE
    kino_adressen.adressid = 32038
```

[And the result is like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2D0W.jpg)

Why is kino_termine not using any index ?
I set it to PK while creating and even added an index afterwards, but none of those helped.

Answer (score 1):

You added an index on the **address** but use the `city` in the `where` clause. Add an index on the `city` then it will be used.

Comment: That's sucha quick and true answer, thank you very much, I didn't know that I had to do it that way :)